# Query optimization using any method

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, query-performance

I need to speed up this query. What can I do?

```
select i.resp_id as id from int_result i, response_set rs, cx_store_child cbu 
where rs.survey_id IN(5550512,5550516,5550521,5550520,5590351,5590384,5679615,5679646,5691634,5699259,5699266,5699270)
        and i.q_id IN(52603091,52251250,52250724,52251333,52919541,52920117,54409178,54409806,54625102,54738933,54739117,54739221) 
        and rs.t >= '2017-08-30 00:00:00' and rs.t <= '2017-09-30 00:00:00' 
        and i.response_set_id = rs.id and rs.cx_business_unit_id = cbu.child_bu_id 
        and cbu.business_unit_id = 30850 
group by rs.cx_business_unit_id, i.a_id, extract(day from rs.t)
```

```
------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name        | Seq_in_index | Column_name     | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| int_result |          0 | PRIMARY         |            1 | id              | A         |   240843099 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| int_result |          1 | q_id            |            1 | q_id            | A         |     1442174 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| int_result |          1 | a_id            |            1 | a_id            | A         |    20070258 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| int_result |          1 | resp_id         |            1 | resp_id         | A         |   120421549 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| int_result |          1 | response_set_id |            1 | response_set_id | A         |    26760344 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| int_result |          1 | survey_id       |            1 | survey_id       | A         |      503855 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| int_result |          1 | survey_id_2     |            1 | survey_id       | A         |     1459655 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| int_result |          1 | survey_id_2     |            2 | q_id            | A         |     2736853 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+------
```

```
--+---------+---------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| response_set |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | id                  | A         |    14307454 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| response_set |          1 | survey_id            |            1 | survey_id           | A         |      223553 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| response_set |          1 | id                   |            1 | id                  | A         |    14307454 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| response_set |          1 | external_id          |            1 | external_id         | A         |        2921 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| response_set |          1 | panel_member_id      |            1 | panel_member_id     | A         |      357686 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| response_set |          1 | email_group          |            1 | email_group         | A         |       21259 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| response_set |          1 | survey_timestamp_idx |            1 | survey_id           | A         |      433559 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| response_set |          1 | survey_timestamp_idx |            2 | t                   | A         |    14307454 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| response_set |          1 | bu_id                |            1 | cx_business_unit_id | A         |        2246 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
```

```
----------------+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table          | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name      | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------------+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| cx_store_child |          0 | PRIMARY          |            1 | id               | A         |       13667 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| cx_store_child |          0 | bu_child_ref     |            1 | business_unit_id | A         |       13667 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cx_store_child |          0 | bu_child_ref     |            2 | child_bu_id      | A         |       13667 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cx_store_child |          1 | cx_feedback_id   |            1 | cx_feedback_id   | A         |         506 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cx_store_child |          1 | business_unit_id |            1 | business_unit_id | A         |       13667 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| cx_store_child |          1 | child_bu_id      |            1 | child_bu_id      | A         |       13667 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------------+------------+------------------+--------------+------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+
```

Comment: Start by changing the implicit joins to explicit joins.

Comment: Extract (day from - isn't this oracle syntax? and can you add your 3rd table definition.

Comment: I tried the same using inner join . It hardly makes difference. Its taking 10 sec to get executed with join which otherwise was 10.16 sec

Comment: The point of using explicit joins is to make it more readable, not to speed it up (as it does exactly the same thing). Can you add: the explain output (write `explain ` infront of your query) and the number of rows you get for your query with and without the `group by`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Please pay special attention to the section on query performance. Then come back here and [edit] your question to provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have an index on `response_set(survey_id, t)`.

Try creating a so-called [compound covering index](https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/06/05/a-rule-of-thumb-for-choosing-column-order-in-indexes/) on

```
response_set(t, survey_id, cx_business_unit_id)
```

This may help optimize the part of your query using that table. Why? Your query calls for a range scan on `t`, and a column used in a range scan must be first in its compound index.

Similarly, an index on `int_result  (q_id, resp_id, response_set_id)` may help extract the data you need from that table.

Some notes:

1. It's hard to tell what your query does. Maybe some explanation will help you get better results here?
2. `and rs.t >= '2017-08-30 00:00:00' and rs.t <= '2017-09-30 00:00:00'` is probably incorrect as to the end of the time range. It probably contains an off-by-one error. Do you want `<` in place of `<=` ? What you have given includes the records with timestamps precisely at midnight on 30-Sep-2017, but no records on that day after midnight.
3. You have one index on `int_result(survey_id, q_id)` and another on `int_result(survey_id)`. The latter index is entirely redundant with the former and you can drop it.
4. You seem to have lots of single-column indexes. Pro tip: don't add such indexes unless you know you need them. They rarely help speed up arbitrary queries and always slow down insertions and updates. Why might you need them? If you have a query you know needs them, or you need to enforce uniqueness. Drop the indexes you don't need.
5. Use 21st-century JOIN syntax instead of the old-timey comma-join syntax as follows.  It's easier to read.

```
   from int_result i 
   join response_set rs    on i.response_set_id = rs.id
   join cx_store_child cbu on  rs.cx_business_unit_id = cbu.child_bu_id
```

Read this. You're maintaining a large database and it's worth your time to learn a lot about indexing.  http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Agree on date querying.  If I want all data up to and including ex: Sep 30, I always do LESS THAN Oct 1.  Prevents all ambiguity of time issues.

Comment: Indeed. Often the problem I noted here comes up with the use of `BETWEEN` for a datestamp range, which is almost never correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways that the Optimizer may attempt to perform the query.  The following indexes give it some flexibility to find the optimal order of hitting the tables:

```
cbu:  INDEX(business_unit_id, child_bu_id)
rs:   INDEX(t, cx_business_unit_id, survey_id)
rs:   INDEX(survey_id, t, cx_business_unit_id)
rs:   INDEX(cx_business_unit_id, survey_id, t)
i:    INDEX(response_set_id, q_id)
i:    INDEX(q_id, response_set_id)
```

I arranged for `rs` and `cbu` to have "covering" indexes in all cases; this helps some.

(Yes, you should change to `JOIN...ON` as O. Jones suggests.  And the rest of his suggestions.)

Before further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; the could be datatype issues, too.

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key is an `INDEX` -- so `INDEX(id)` in `rs` is redundant.